# Creating calendar that can't choose past days and only can choose certain amount of future days

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to create calendar in Vue.js. That calendar can only select days from current day to the next 30 days. Days before current date can't be picked, and days after those first 30 days from current date also can't be picked.

I am new to Vue.js but I have done this in JavaScript as you can see here:
https://codepen.io/tarik-bisevac/pen/WNemOXO

But I have problem with implementing this code in Vue.js

Here is what I tried to do in Vue:

```
let app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{
        min: dtToday,
        max: maxDate
    },
    computed: {
        dtToday(){
            new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10)
firstDate.setAttribute('min',dtToday)
firstDate.setAttribute('max',dtToday)
        },
        maxDate(){
            let month = new Date().getMonth()+2
let day = new Date().getDate()
let year = new Date().getFullYear()

new Date(`${month}/${day}/${year}`).toISOString().slice(0,10)
        }
    }
})
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="app">
        <input type='date' v-model='min'> 
        <input type='date' v-model='max'> 
    </div>
```

It shows me this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'dtToday' before initialization

I tried with methods and computed properties, but I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: This cannot work because the data is evaluated at the time of component creation before the computed. So you should not call computed property in data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call computed from data because data is needed at the time of component creation and computed not available before creation.

So you can set min max value blank in data and calculate it after creation in created() or mounted() life cycle hook.

Try like this :

```js
let app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{
        min:'',
        max:'',      
    },
    created(){
      this.comuteMinMaxDate();
    },
    methods:{
      comuteMinMaxDate(){
        let todayDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10);
        this.min =todayDate;
        let month = new Date().getMonth()+2
        let day = new Date().getDate()
        let year = new Date().getFullYear()
        // create html input format
        let maxDate = new Date(`${month}/${day}/${year}`).toISOString().slice(0,10);
        this.max= maxDate;
      }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
     <input type='date' :min="min" :max="min"> 
     <input type='date' :min="min" :max="max"> 
</div>
```